Second moment of a truncated normal random variable
I'm having a hard time computing an expression that appears in a paper on sums of lognormal variable (link to the original paper, equation (66), the paper describes the Schwarz Yeh approximation for sums of lognormal variables).
So I have a normal random variable $W$, with mean $\mu_W$ and variance $\sigma_W^2$.
The expression I need to work on is $I = \int_{0}^{+\infty} w^2 f_W(w)dw$
where
$f_W$ is the normal PDF of W, meaning $f_W(w) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_W^2}} \exp\left( -\frac{(w-\mu_W)^2}{2\sigma_W^2}\right)$.
In other words, I need to develop the expression for the second moment of a truncated normal random variable.
According to the original paper, we can get

This paper seems really reliable except for a bunch of unfortunate typos, it has been around for decades and is the starting point for several other works, so I don't believe there's an error in it. But I've spent hours trying to get this expression and I'm nowhere near. Am I missing something here, or is there really a mistake ?
For clarity, when I develop the expression I get $I = (\mu_W^2 + \sigma_W^2)  \Phi\left( \frac{\mu_W}{\sigma_W} \right) + \frac{\mu_W \sigma_W}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left( -\frac{\mu_W^2}{2\sigma_W^2} \right)$
Could someone give me pointers please ?
edit: $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF.
